# Best Approach to Zipping up a Folder in Google Cloud Storage using Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

My Google App Engine Go project creates a zip of multiple files in a "folder" that's in Google Cloud Storage.  It used to be pretty quick when it was implemented in the BlobStore using the now deprecated and removed Files API. I recently converted the code to use Google Cloud Storage and now the performance is really bad and sometimes will timeout. The files that are being zipped are between 1K and 2M in size.

I'm looking for any advice to improve zipping up file contents. The code below is what I wrote for compressing multiple files in the cloud to a new zip file in the cloud. It can take a long time to execute and requires loading the entire contents (See PERFORMANCE ISSUE below) of each file into memory before writing it to the zip.  There has to be a better way.

```
// Pack a folder into zip file
func (cloud *Cloud) Pack(srcFolder string, fileName string, contentType string, metaData *map[string]string) {

    log.Infof(cloud.c, "Packing bucket %v folder %v to file %v", cloud.bucket, srcFolder, fileName) 

    srcFolder = fmt.Sprintf("%v/", srcFolder)
    query := &storage.Query{Prefix: srcFolder, Delimiter: "/"}

    objs, err := storage.ListObjects(cloud.ctx, cloud.bucket, query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to list bucket %q: %v", cloud.bucket, err)
        return
    }

    totalFiles := len(objs.Results)
    if totalFiles == 0 {
        log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to find objects found in folder %q: %v", cloud.bucket, srcFolder)
        return
    }

    // create storage file for writing
    log.Infof(cloud.c, "Writing new zip file to %v/%v for %v files", cloud.bucket, fileName, totalFiles)
    storageWriter := storage.NewWriter(cloud.ctx, cloud.bucket, fileName)

    // add optional content type and meta data  
    if len(contentType) > 0 { storageWriter.ContentType = contentType }
    if metaData != nil { storageWriter.Metadata = *metaData }

    // Create a buffer to write our archive to.
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    // Create a new zip archive to memory buffer
    zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(buf)

    // go through each file in the folder
    for _, obj := range objs.Results {

        log.Infof(cloud.c, "Packing file %v of size %v to zip file", obj.Name, obj.Size)
        //d.dumpStats(obj)

        // read file in our source folder from storage - io.ReadCloser returned from storage
        storageReader, err := storage.NewReader(cloud.ctx, cloud.bucket, obj.Name)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to read from bucket %q file %q: %v", cloud.bucket, obj.Name, err)
            return  
        }
        defer storageReader.Close()

        // PERFORMANCE ISSUE: have to load the entire file into memory to get random access from the cloud
        slurp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(storageReader)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to read data from bucket %q file %q: %v", cloud.bucket, obj.Name, err)
            return
        }

        // grab just the filename from directory listing (don't want to store paths in zip)
        _, zipFileName := filepath.Split(obj.Name)

        newFileName := strings.ToLower(zipFileName)

        // add filename to zip
        zipFile, err := zipWriter.Create(newFileName)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to create zip file from bucket %q file %q: %v", cloud.bucket, zipFileName, err)
            return
        }

        // write entire file into zip archive
        _, err = zipFile.Write(slurp)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to write zip file from bucket %q file %q: %v", cloud.bucket, zipFileName, err)
            return
        }

        // flush that to buffer so we can write it off now
        //err = zipFile.Flush()
        //if err != nil {
        //  d.errorf("pack: unable to flush write of zip file from bucket %q, file %q: %v", cloud.bucket, zipFileName, err)
        //  //return
        //}

        // now drain all that buffered zip data to the cloud storage file   
        log.Infof(cloud.c, "Writing zip buffer of size %v to cloud storage file %v", buf.Len(), fileName)   
        _, err = buf.WriteTo(storageWriter)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to write data to bucket %q file %q: %v", cloud.bucket, fileName, err)   
            return          
        }
    }

    // Make sure to check the error on Close.
    log.Infof(cloud.c, "Closing zip writer")    
    err = zipWriter.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to close zip file writer from bucket %q file %q : %v", cloud.bucket, fileName, err)
    }

    // write any leftover data
    if buf.Len() > 0 {
        // now drain all that buffered zip data to the cloud storage file   
        // log.Infof(cloud.c, "Packing zip buffer of size %v to cloud storage file %v", buf.Len(), fileName)    
        _, err := buf.WriteTo(storageWriter)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to write data to bucket %q file %q: %v", cloud.bucket, fileName, err)               
        }
    }

    // close up final write file
    //log.Infof(cloud.c, "Closing cloud storage file %v", fileName) 
    if err := storageWriter.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to close bucket %q file %q: %v", cloud.bucket, fileName, err)
        return
    }

    // success!
    log.Infof(cloud.c, "Packed files to new cloud storage file %v successful!", fileName)   
}
```

Comment: I see no reason you need to load it all into memory. Why do you need random access from the file? You just need to io.Copy from the src to the zip. I also don't see why you need to load the zip file into memory. You can just stream it out as it is being built.

Comment: I'll look into it again but I'm pretty sure that was the first thing I tried...

Comment: @StephenWeinberg The Zip Reader requires an io.ReaderAt interface which is why you have to load the entire thing into a buffer for random access (see: https://golang.org/src/archive/zip/reader.go) from the cloud because cloud storage only gives you a ReadCloser interface (see: https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/storage#example-NewReader)  This is why the BlobStore was so much faster for me.  Am I missing something?

Comment: That is for reading. You are writing.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg Thanks!  That was clearly a mistake from copy/paste of my Unpack routine.  Also do not need to write to a buffer first and can write directly to the storage file.  So that's 2 big improvements there.  Cheers

Comment: @StephenWeinberg Do you do any consulting?  I'm in DC.

Comment: Sometimes, but I am off the grid for the next week and a half. If you are interested I can talk more after Aug 4th. My email is stephen@q5comm.com. I am in NY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen who suggested not loading the file into memory buffers when writing to a zip.  Here is the fixed code for reference:

```
// Pack a folder into zip file
func (cloud *Cloud) Pack(srcFolder string, fileName string, contentType string, metaData *map[string]string) bool {

    log.Infof(cloud.c, "Packing bucket %v folder %v to file %v", cloud.bucket, srcFolder, fileName) 

    srcFolder = fmt.Sprintf("%v/", srcFolder)
    query := &storage.Query{Prefix: srcFolder, Delimiter: "/"}

    objs, err := storage.ListObjects(cloud.ctx, cloud.bucket, query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to list bucket %q: %v", cloud.bucket, err)
        return false
    }

    totalFiles := len(objs.Results)
    if totalFiles == 0 {
        log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to find objects found in folder %q: %v", cloud.bucket, srcFolder)
        return false
    }

    // create storage file for writing
    log.Infof(cloud.c, "Writing new zip file to %v/%v for %v files", cloud.bucket, fileName, totalFiles)
    storageWriter := storage.NewWriter(cloud.ctx, cloud.bucket, fileName)
    defer storageWriter.Close()

    // add optional content type and meta data  
    if len(contentType) > 0 { storageWriter.ContentType = contentType }
    if metaData != nil { storageWriter.Metadata = *metaData }

    // Create a new zip archive to memory buffer
    zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(storageWriter)

    // go through each file in the folder
    for _, obj := range objs.Results {

        log.Infof(cloud.c, "Packing file %v of size %v to zip file", obj.Name, obj.Size)
        //d.dumpStats(obj)

        // read file in our source folder from storage - io.ReadCloser returned from storage
        storageReader, err := storage.NewReader(cloud.ctx, cloud.bucket, obj.Name)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to read from bucket %q file %q: %v", cloud.bucket, obj.Name, err)
            return false
        }
        defer storageReader.Close()

        // grab just the filename from directory listing (don't want to store paths in zip)
        _, zipFileName := filepath.Split(obj.Name)
        newFileName := strings.ToLower(zipFileName)

        // add filename to zip
        zipFile, err := zipWriter.Create(newFileName)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to create zip file from bucket %q file %q: %v", cloud.bucket, zipFileName, err)
            return false
        }

        // copy from storage reader to zip writer   
        _, err = io.Copy(zipFile, storageReader)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Failed to copy from storage reader to zip file: %v", err)
            return false
        }   
    }

    // Make sure to check the error on Close.
    log.Infof(cloud.c, "Closing zip writer")    
    err = zipWriter.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(cloud.c, "Packing failed to close zip file writer from bucket %q file %q : %v", cloud.bucket, fileName, err)
        return false
    }

    // success!
    log.Infof(cloud.c, "Packed files to new cloud storage file %v successful!", fileName)   
    return true
}
```

Comment: Wrote a version of this for use outside of google app engine, but still in go: https://gist.github.com/moorage/a7300dee720e694aa89fd152b2b2c69d

Comment: @tmoore  Does this code compress / zip multiple files in google cloud storage bucket into single zip file without downloading them locally ?                                                        I couldn't understand that part in your code since I haven't used Go lang. Please clarify.